# How to play default TICK sound?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to connect Android OS default tick sound (for example, the sound you hear when you long click Home button and select previous app to start) with my button click. I know how to play sounds via MediaPlayer, but I do not know where to search for this default tick sound. It had to be in some default resources, but I could not find it.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);  
mp.setLooping(false);
mp.start();
```

Anyone can help?

PS. this sound will be activated inside of onClick method.
PPS. I know I can user /raw dir, but I do not think there's a need for it. Not to say, it's cooler to play this tick sound prepared for user's phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: This is a pretty old answer. Check Roberto Tyley's answer below.**

I think the sound that you are looking for is and is in - `/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg`

I think you can give that path to the `SetDataSource` API of the mediaplayer. But I am not really sure if it will have the same name in all android phones.

There might be a better way to query for default click sound..

Comment: You would be better served copying that file into your own project. That file is not part of the Android SDK. I am not aware of a way in the SDK to request a playback of that click sound.

Comment: True, since there is no garuntee that the OEM will retain the click sound from Android source. But is it legal for me to copy the click sound from android source into my own project?

Comment: Well, right now that's tough to answer, since android.git.kernel.org is still a bit of a mess. But, if the file is a part of the Android Open Source Project, it should be licensed under the Apache License 2.0, just as the rest of the code and assets are.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't try to reference the `/system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg` system file by path, please see `view.playSoundEffect()` in my answer below.

Comment: Agreed, didn't about it back then.. actually till I read your answer now :)

Comment: Would you need to root to access that folder on a pc? I can't seem to find it when I plug my phone in (Not for development purposes)

Comment: Well no, you don't need to root the device. But you will also not be able to see that file when you plug in your phone to a PC, because when the phone is plugged in it only mounts the sdcard folder. You can use a file manager application to view this file but if you want to pull it out of the device, there are a couple of ways - one send the file over bt, lan etc. second use adb to pull the file.

Answer (score 69):

You can play the default Android 'tick' sound using the [`view.playSoundEffect()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29) method on any View - surprisingly enough, all views can play a selection of 'system' sounds:

```
view.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
```

and don't forget to add this to your view :

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
```

This is probably the simplest answer to your problem :)

Comment: For some reason, this stopped working. Any clue what could be the problem? Please take a look at my code: `out.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { out.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK); ...}}}`  Thanks!!

Comment: Solved by adding `android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"` in the layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you want control over the volume of the sound, use the `AudioManager` system service. Plus this can be used from a Service if you don't have a view handy.

```
// get the AudioManager once onCreate or similar
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

...
// Play a System Sound
audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

// OR at 50% Volume
audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK, 0.5F);
```

If you are on Google GLASS you can use the `com.google.android.glass.media.Sounds` constants

```
audioManager.playSoundEffect(Sounds.TAP);
```

The following are included in Sounds

DISALLOWED, ERROR, SUCCESS, TAP, SELECTED, DISMISSED

Answer (score 7):

**You can use tick, beep or any kind of inbuilt sound by [Tone Generator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html)**

```
ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
```

Answer (score 6):

Roberto Tyley's answer is correct.

You can play a sound from every view just by calling it this way:

```
Button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);   
            }
        });
```

Just note that the sound will not play if touch sounds are off by default. This is set in the general device sound preferences (Settings-->Sound-->Audible or on newer OS: Options > Sound > Touch)

Also, if this setting is set, most click events will trigger the click sound anyway!